# Rpi LDAP Netboot + SD Crypt

Tags: security, encryption, ldap, raspberry-pi, nfs

**Hello Everyone,**
I am doing a project with RPI, I want Rpi to boot by internet, user login must be check with a server, and i want the sd to be encrypted.
I want all of these because I do not want the information inside Rpi to be hack, i want to protect all the information and the use of this by a server.

Is this possible? How could i do it? What do you app recommend me? I need an orientation to continue reading and investigating.
Best regards
**Thank you for your help!**
JoseLuis

Comment: This is really too broad a question.  You're looking for tutorials and this site focuses more on specific programming and code issues.  Try a search engine or someplace like Google+ that should have groups focused on this.

Comment: I do not know what to search, that why. First you can tell me if using LDAP, OPENSSL, NETBOOT and DISK CRYPT i am going to protect the data? My be i am exaggerating and I only need LDAP OPENSLL and Disk Crypt. you can recommend me what thing I need to use... Then I will do my research, I am not asking you to give me step by step, I am asking a orientation and an advice...

Comment: I want to be clear that I'm not criticizing your interest. I just wanted to point out that this site isn't good at answering open ended questions and that you'll have better results with searches or other sites.  I have been in your position.  There are times when it can be hard to find info and it is frustrating.

Comment: try this sister site - http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Matt I ve just asked